# getting binary errror with Watchkit app on submission from Application Loader on Testflight

Tags: watchkit, xcode8, testflight

I am using Xcode 8 and trying to upload my watchKit app to Testflight but its failing all the time.so far i have tried these options,

1. tried uploading it from Application Loader 3.6 and get invalid swift support, invalid watchkit support,and invalid executable error.
2. tried from Xcode 8. The app validates succesfully but upon upload to store, it just gets stuck. when i refresh, i do get an upload sccessful message but nothing is visible on testflight.

how to upload my watch app on testflight? please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the version of your app to test on the [iTunes Connect website](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)?

I hope I'm not stating the obvious here, but if you:

1. Select your app in the "My Apps" section
2. Select the "TestFlight" tab at the top
3. Select "Internal Testing" on the left hand menu
4. Click on the "Select version to test" link in the page

Uploading an archive with a new version number doesn't automatically add it to TestFlight, so you have to go through this procedure every time you change version number (or on the first upload).

Once it's added, you should see the app appear in the TestFlight app on your phone. When it also has a Apple Watch app, and you have a watch paired with your phone, TestFlight will also install the app to your watch.

Hope that helps!